# How to create PIE chart with slice inside outer circle

Tags: highcharts

I want to create PIE chart using Highchart as below image, please suggest a solution-

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use two pie series with different `innerSize` and `size` properties, for example:

```
    series: [{
        data: [{
            y: 1,
            color: 'blue'
        }]
    }, {
        size: '70%',
        innerSize: '30%',
        data: [{
            y: 3,
            color: 'green'
        }, {
            y: 12,
            color: 'blue',
            showInLegend: false
        }]
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4b1phj67/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie